# How can I integrate Third Party payment gateway in BIGCOMMERCE store?

Tags: payment-gateway, bigcommerce

From: Tictocd.com
TO: `Bigcommerce`

My boss don't want the 2CHECKOUT payment gateway method, which is only supported Brunei Dollar because of the review they conducted. One of the `BIGCOMMERCE` Live Chat Operator said that we can use a third party payment method which is `BIDB` (Brunei Islam Brunei Darussalam). `BIBD` said that they will provide `PHP` script that will help us to do the payment method online, but how we can integrate that script in our store?

I am anticipating for your positive response with regards in this matter. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it isn't recommended nor easy to integrate a third party payment gateway. This requires having your own web service set up to make API calls to the payment gateway and passing the details from the checkout page. If you would like to go this route, using [ActiveMerchant](http://activemerchant.org/) would provide the path of least resistance.

Bigcommerce technical support will not provide PHP scripts and PHP/Ruby/server side language scripts cannot be executed on their servers by users.