# bigcommerce app development - custom payment portal

Tags: bigcommerce

I need to create a custom payment portal for my BigCommerce store.

So that I can capture credit card information and store that in my own system.

Given that bigcommerce supports the development of private apps - can anyone suggest an approach as to how to write an app that would allow me to change the checkout screen to not display, say the paypal checkout, but instead display my own?

There are 3rd party apps that allow you to capture payment information to facilitate recurring payments, and others to change the checkout page layout, so it seems possible to inject javascript into the bigcommerce screens.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34986588/how-can-i-integrate-third-party-payment-gateway-in-bigcommerce-store -- you can also check out the apps rebillia & recurhub.

Comment: I don't want to use a 3rd party billing app - I want to build my own private billing app.

Comment: The third party billing apps don't object JavaScript and there isn't a good way to do so today. I would be concerned with the PCI requirements placed on you if you did so.