# How to add new Payment Gateway in bigcommerce?

Tags: api, payment-gateway, bigcommerce

In Bigcommerce, how I can add new payment gateway if I haven't found payment gateway which I require in list:
https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Available-Payment-Gateways/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, all the gateways on that list have been added by BigCommerce as it requires changes to our core app. It is possible to customize blueprint checkout in a workaround to support a gateway not on the list.

[How can I integrate Third Party payment gateway in BIGCOMMERCE store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34986588/how-can-i-integrate-third-party-payment-gateway-in-bigcommerce-store)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have used ActiveMerchant in shopify and added successfully gateway there. But I am looking similiar API scope in Bigcommerce. Can I dynamically make changes in bigcommerce theme by using any API request. : https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/theme

Comment: On checkout page , I want to make some changes like I want to add more options for 'How would you like to pay'. Here I want to add my custom payment gateway option. Is it possible to add new html page dynamically by using API request. Please guide.

Comment: No, you cannot dynamically make changes via the API to a theme.

Comment: Hi Alyss , Can you inform about any new enhancements or new updates for bigcommerce API in coming next months. Thanks

Comment: What I release about the API is limited in nature and I try to keep to specific questions that have been asked.